# How to use Dynamic IP Restrictions in IIS?

Tags: iis

I have an IIS 10 website behind AWS CloudFront.

I would like to use IP Dynamic restrictions to deny IP addresses based on the number of requests over a period of time.

- In IP and Domain restrictions settings I have "Enable Proxy Mode" checked.

[image]

- **X-Forwarded-For** is forwarded to my website.

When adding a certain user IP Address to test **X-Forwarded-For**, it's properly blocked. So the website blocks requests coming from this specific user address and not from AWS CloudFront which is the expected behavior.

[image]

However when enabling **IP Dynamic restrictions**, all the requests coming from AWS CloudFront are blocked. So **IP Dynamic restrictions** doesn't take into account the real end user IP address.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What you really should focus on is services like https://aws.amazon.com/waf/

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your comment. WAF doesn't work well mainly for this reason : "AWS WAF checks the rate of requests every 30 seconds, and counts requests for the prior 5 minutes each time." What about if I would like to block requests based on a much lower rate ? Say 5 requests per 1 second ? WAF won't work for that. Thanks though

Comment: "if I would like to block requests based on a much lower rate ? Say 5 requests per 1 second ? " isn't realistic. When premium service providers like Cloudflare can only offer rate limiting plan for durations as short as 10 seconds https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001635128-Configuring-Cloudflare-Rate-Limiting you should think twice about what you really need to achieve. IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions is cheap (as Microsoft does not cost you more), but when its rules take effect the bad traffic is already on the server, which is often too late.

Comment: @LexLi I think you don't have any idea about the architecture nor the bottleneck (what I really need to protect). My server works as a reverse proxy of a specific application which is the bottleneck. I don't mind getting traffic to IIS server since, in my specific case, it can handle 1000 x times more trafic than this specific application. So I'm still fine with getting traffic to IIS and then block it at a low rates : 5 requests per 1 second. Thanks though.